# Deploy error in converted application ("Centennial")

Tags: .net, winforms, uwp, desktop-bridge

Has anyone succeeded in manually converting an application to a Windows Store application?

I created a winforms application (basically the template application) and used the process outlined on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-manual-conversion)  . The app opens and immediately closes. (The error given by WACK is that the file has failed the AppContainerCheck check.) I tried changing details in the appxmanifest and the exe etc. in order to make it work. With no luck.

So I was wondering if the process in the link is simply mistaken. Has anyone actually succeeded in using that process?

Comment: *"I tried many workarounds with no luck."* - Workarounds for what?

Comment: @IInspectable I meant I tried changing details in the appxmanifest and the exe etc. in order to make it work.

Comment: So you just create a blank winform application and manually convert it to UWP app? Are you trying to run the WACK and validate this app? If so, could you please share this WACK report or the completed project with manifest? Did the process work for them with the app provided in the corresponding github sample? https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT Thanks. I have since solved the problem.

Comment: @ispiro Use my suggestion? May I know details?

Comment: @FranklinChen-MSFT I originally "fixed" the EntryPoint to the project's one. By the way. If you're an expert on Centennial things - perhaps you know [how to get the protocol activation arguments in a Centennial app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39436602/get-protocol-activation-args-in-project-centennial-app)?