# Get protocol activation args in "Project Centennial" app

Tags: uwp, windows-store-apps, win-universal-app, desktop-bridge

How can I access the protocol activation arguments in a Winforms app that's converted into a UWP app?

The problem is that the `OnActivated` method is absent so I can't get the `IActivatedEventArgs`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you want to handle file types in which case you can check `Environment.GetCommandLineArgs()` as normal for arguments. The second argument will be the file or protocol activated.

Answer (score 0):

> How can I access the protocol activation arguments in a Winforms app that's converted into a UWP app?

The lifecycle can't be integrated in Converted UWP app. Basically the common scenarios are enabling Toast notification, Live tile, App service and Background task.

Please check [Supported UWP APIs for converted desktop apps](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/porting/desktop-to-uwp-supported-api#apis-supported-in-both-converted-apps-and-desktop-applications)

Some official samples: [DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples](https://github.com/Microsoft/DesktopBridgeToUWP-Samples/tree/master/Samples/JourneyAcrossTheBridge)